# Difference between scripting and non scripting language

Tags: scripting

I am wondering what is difference between scripting and non scripting language. For example like LUA and C++. Because in game development I often read that they are hiring programmer who must know scripting language. Thank you!

Comment: google is your friend.

Comment: That's what happens when you let HR write your job specs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some of this is somewhat historical in nature.

Non-scripted languages like C and C++ are compiled into "raw machine code" (RMC).
That RMC is then run directly on the machine. Note that RMC is typically
very specific to the underlying CPU/hardware AND to the supporting Operating
System. So if you want to run a C program on both linux and windows, it has to be
compiled for each (two copies to maintain and distribute).

A scripted language is typically NOT compiled. Instead, the source
code is passed to an interpreter that understands the language. The
interpreter itself is typically written in a language that is
itself compiled to RMC. The interpreter's task is to read the
scripted language, and translate that into operations done by RMC.

The line has blurred in recent years (decades?) with the advent of
systems like Java. With languages like Java, source code is
compiled to an intermediate/portable language, and the Java Virtual
Machine handles the translation of that portable language into
operations for the target CPU/OS.